# Oil change on Volvo turbo

Tags: oil

I have a 2006 Volvo XC90 2.5 turbo with 175000 on it. I have kept up with maintenance totally. The other day I changed the oil and I used the normal Mobil 1 synthetic high mileage 10w/30 but this time I used 1 guart of Mobil 1 synthetic oil stabilizer along with regular oil I use. Well I started the engine to get the new oil moved around and it ran good but after checking oil level it was a little high about 1/4 inch above the upper mark on the dipstick and I heard a little slapping noise. Well today I went out to recheck it after I had ran about 40 miles around town and the level was ok but when I took the oil cap off to check on the slapping noise I hear a loud slapping sucking noise that was much worst than the other day. Help,have I ruined a $5000 engine? I used the correct amount of oil like I always do.
Bill

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

No you didn't ruin your engine yet. However having more oil than thr max mark is bad. Can cause some problems. So i suggest you if the oil is too much to drain a bit. Also don't remove dipstick or oil cap while engine is running. Your engine is designed to pull a vacuum when the system is operating correctly. When you introduce an air leak you cause a change in the entire system which typically results in a rough idle and sucking sounds coming from inside the engine.

Comment: Thank for the info. I think I’m going to change the oil again and leave out the oil stabilizer.